# Debian 9 - additional IP

Tags: debian, ip, failover

I have a server with Debian 9.2. (Soyoustart)

I want to add 2 additional IP addresses.

Is it correct to add them in that way ?

In the file "/etc/systemd/network/50-default.network", to these lines :

```
[Address]
Address=22.33.44.55/32 #for the IP1
Label=failover1 # optional
Address=66.77.88.99/32 #for the IP2
Label=failover2 # optional
```

And then to restart the system.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overall it's the correct way to do it as per the recently updated instructions in 
https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/dedicated/network-ipaliasing/#debian-9-ubuntu-17-fedora-26-and-arch-linux
because the document says to backup then edit `/etc/systemd/network/50-default.network` with the following:

```
[Address]
Address=22.33.44.55/32
Label=failover1 # Optional
```

But it states that a reboot is not needed, since you can issue `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` and you're good to go...

**EDIT:** 
Adding more failovers requires each IP to be declared in its own `[Address]` section, as the example below:
    [Address]
    Address=22.33.44.55/32
    Label=failover1 # Optional

```
[Address]
Address=23.34.45.56/32
Label=failover2 # Optional
.
.
.
[Address]
Address=99.98.76.54/32
Label=failover-n # Optional
```

Issue `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` and voilà.